# After 2nd <li> the submenu is disappearing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I did change Bootstrap 3 drop-down behavior from *on click* to *on hover* by adding some CSS

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

It's working. The sub-menu has more than 2 `<li>` tags and when hovering below the 2nd `<li>` the sub-menu will disappear.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true">Exhibitor <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Opportunities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Exhibitor List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Market Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Floor Plan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I can hover until `<li><a href="#">Exhibitor List</a></li>` only.

When I reach `<li><a href="#">Market Information</a></li>` the sub-menu disappears.

Comment: In the code snippet you gave us is everything okay. Show us the problematic code, ideally working fiddle.

Comment: http://mcreatives.com/adyapana2015/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this element:

```
<body>
    […]
    <section style="position: absolute;left: 0;right: 0;top: 100px;z-index:4000;">[…]</section>
</body>
```

It is an invisible stripe above the menu at around the third element. As it has a higher `z-index` you'll leave the menu when hovering this element.

PS: It's the container that holds the links *Exhibitor list*, *Floor plan* and *Opportunities*.